# join two tables with similar columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a question about joining two tables in mysql.

I have this data model:

```
timeline:
structure: i.imgur.com/THmV5hp.jpg
data: i.imgur.com/YaabHtf.jpg

timeline_personal:
structure: i.imgur.com/H0VzTMw.jpg
data: i.imgur.com/rX3NhOb.jpg
```

i like to join 2 tables in differents rows. I try with left, inner and right join but its not possible. Results retrieve me in similar rows. I like a result like shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Nv2.jpg) link:

This is a difficult question :P

Comment: Show us the table structure and what you have tried

Comment: Please, get rid of structure in pictures and use [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) for that

Comment: table timeline: structure: http://i.imgur.com/THmV5hp.jpg data: http://i.imgur.com/YaabHtf.jpg

Comment: table timeline_personal: structure: http://i.imgur.com/H0VzTMw.jpg data: http://i.imgur.com/rX3NhOb.jpg

Comment: Fiddle dont return me any data. I put the dump data and structure table here: http://pastebin.com/9sUgTscC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the required result using following query:

```
  select 
      concat('T-',timeline.TimelineId), timeline.UsuarioId, timeline.TimelineFecha, "" Timeline, timeline.Evento, timeline.JuegoId, 0 TimelinePadre 
  from 
      timeline 
  union 
  select 
     concat('TP-',timeline_personal.TimelineId), timeline_personal.UsuarioId, timeline_personal.TimelineFecha, timeline_personal.Timeline, "0" Evento, "0" JuegoId, timeline_personal.TimelinePadre 
  from 
     timeline_personal 
  order by UsuarioId
```

Comment: This query return me this data: http://i.imgur.com/sh4TBiF.jpg I need this data structure: http://i.imgur.com/QZM7bsS.jpg

Comment: much thanks for your solution but u dont understand my problem. maybe i think a imposible query. in this data result: http://i.imgur.com/QZM7bsS.jpg the 1,4 row correspond a timeline_personal table row 2,3 row, a timeline row for timeline table

Comment: This is possible query. If I have that database structure at my side I will definitely help you to get that result.

Comment: I have 27 tables in my db. I need the complete db? I can extract the data model mysql workbench, just tell me

Comment: Can you send me the dump of these two tables, so that I can help you.

Comment: AWESOME.A more complicated challenge.. You could nest the results they had TimelinePadre with TimelineId?

many thanks for your help. my sql knowledge its too basic.